# Delete line from file at specified line number in bourne shell

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I'm making an appointment tracking script in Bourne Shell and need to delete an appointment from the text file. How do I delete a line from a file leaving no white space if I have the line number? The file looks like this:

```
1:19:2013:Saturday:16.00:20.30:Poker  
1:24:2013:Thursday:11.00:11.45:Project meeting  
1:24:2013:Thursday:14.00:15.10:CSS Meeting
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To delete line 5, do:

```
sed -i '5d' file.txt
```

For a variable line number:

```
sed -i "${line}d" file.txt
```

If the `-i` option isn't available in your flavor of sed, you can emulate it with a temp file:

```
sed "${line}d" file.txt > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file.txt
```

Comment: On MacOS X -i requires a parameter for a backup file extension.  You can omit it with a empty string to get the same behaviour as desired:  `sed -i "" '5d' file.txt`

Comment: On my system, when processing large files, `sed` appears an order of magnitude slower than a simple combination of `head` and `tail`: here's an example of the faster way without in-place mode: `delete-line() { local filename="$1"; local lineNum="$2"; head -n $((lineNum-1)) "$filename"; tail +$((lineNum+1)) "$filename"; }`

Answer (score 4):

To delete by appointement (line) number:

```
sed -i '3d' input
```

To delete by name:

```
sed -i '/:Poker/d' input
```

If the in-place (`-i`) option does not work on your system the you can do:

```
sed '/:Poker/d' input > input.tmp && mv input.tmp input
```

Comment: POSIX sed does not support sed -i.  Since we are using Bourne here, there is a possibility this is not Linux.  It won't work in Solaris /usr/bin/sed for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quickie using awk:

```
lineToDelete=$1
awk "NR != $lineToDelete"
```

Comment: This doesn't delete the line from the file. It prints the file to STDOUT, except this line.